# Anchor tag moves when browser resized

Tags: css

I'm working on an assignment for a class, and I have an anchor tag that is moving when I resize the browser, I would like it to stay positioned on the pen graphic, you will see the problem here: http://chrisallie.com/index.html

Thanks!

```
CSS:
#contact {
position: fixed;
display: block;
font-family: Century Gothic;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
color: rgb(0, 0, 153);
transform: rotate(-77deg);
line-height: 30px;
width: 150px;
height: 20px;
margin: -300px 0px 0px 1335px;
}

HTML:
    <div id="main-content">
<a href="index.html" id="home">Home</a>
<a href="index.html" id="webcoding">Web<br />Coding<br />seminar<br /><span>Don't miss!</span></a>
<a href="index.html" id="javascript">Javascript<br />10:00</a>
<a href="index.html" id="photoshop">Photoshop<br />Lesson 01 due!</a>
<a href="index.html" id="illustrator">guest speaker<br />Illustrator<br />2:00-3:00</a>
<a href="index.html" id="php">PHP<br />5:00-10:00</a>
    </div>
<a href="index.html" id="contact">Drop us a line!</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the anchor tag inside `<div id="main-content">`

Then give `#main-content position:relative` and give the anchor `position:absolute` (remove all of the fixed positioning stuff)

You can now position the anchor relative to the `#main-content` div, you'll need to give it a negative value for `right` but I think that may be unavoidable in this case.

You'll need to tweak the right and bottom (or top) values for the anchor tag, but you should be able to do it using the above.

Comment: Oh, you'll also need to get rid of the margin on the anchor tag.

Comment: Yeah, exactly! Thanks so much for your time..and fast response!

Answer (score 0):

1. Move "Drop us a line" into the div
2. Add `position:relative` to #main-content